# DatePickerDialog is displaying random number instead of month selected

Tags: java, android, date, datepickerdialog

I am using DatePickerDialog  to select a date and display it in an EditText field, I am doing the same for both departureDateEditText field and returnDateEditText fields. Everything seems to be working except for the month that is displayed when a date is selected from the DatePicker. Instead of returning the month selected, it returns a random number (usually between 01 and 50) in place of the month. The date_template used is "dd/mm/yyyy". Below is my code, any help on how to fix this would be appreciated. I have looked at many other solutions to this but I couldn't find anything that worked.

```
    final Calendar departureCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    final Calendar returnCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    final String myFormat = getResources().getString(R.string.date_template);
    final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.ENGLISH);

    final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener departureDate = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            departureCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            departureCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            departureCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

            departureDateEditText.setText(dateFormat.format(departureCalendar.getTime()));
        }
    };

    final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener returnDate = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            returnCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            returnCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            returnCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

            returnDateEditText.setText(dateFormat.format(returnCalendar.getTime()));
        }
    };

    departureDateEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, departureDate, departureCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    departureCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), departureCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
        }
    });

    returnDateEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, returnDate, returnCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    returnCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), returnCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: do `month+1` , by default `0=January`

Comment: That's not the issue I'm having, I'm aware of that problem. My problem is that I could select October and it will return 48 as the month for example

Comment: try `dd/MM/yyyy`

Comment: That's fixed the problem, thanks very much

Comment: i am glad that i could help